# Is this MVC in javascript?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Despite I have been using MVC in PHP many times, I found out that it is quite different in Javascript. I'm reading MVC in Javascript over the web, but many of them have a different implementation. I came up with a simple MVC, but I think this is not correct. Is this acceptable or completely wrong?

```
var AppView = View.extend({

    init: function()
    {

        // listen to Model changes
        this.listen("counterChanged", $.proxy( this.updateCounter, this ));

        // assign click event; call controller method
        this.container.find("#increase").click( this.callback( this.Controller, "increase" ));
        this.container.find("#decrease").click( this.callback( this.Controller, "decrease" ));
    },


    updateCounter: function( evtData )
    {
        this.container.find("#counter").html( evtData.newValue );
    }

});

var AppController = Controller.extend({

    increase: function()
    {
        this.Model.update("counter", this.Model.get('counter') + 1 );

    },

    decrease: function()
    {
        this.Model.update("counter", this.Model.get('counter') - 1 );

    }

});


var AppModel = Model.extend({


    onUpdate_counter: function( newValue )
    {
        this.fireEvent("counterChanged",{
            newValue: newValue
        })
    }

});




var App = {}

$(document).ready(function(){

    App.Model = new AppModel({
        counter: 0
    });
    App.Controller = new AppController( App.Model );
    App.View = new AppView("#app", App.Controller );    

    App.Model.setView( App.View );

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='app'>

    <div id='counter'>0</div>

    <a id='increase'>Increae</a>
    <a id='decrease'>Decrease</a>

</div>
```

View listens to changes in the model and assigns events to html anchors. View calls the controller when the anchors are clicked then controller updates the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classic 1979-type MVC:

- controller updates models
- models update views via listeners

PHP/Rails (web request/response in general) is a slightly different type of MVC (constricted by the request/response nature of the web):

- controllers update models
- controllers take data from models and send it to views

In both types, view events trigger controller actions.

Comment: clyfe // in your opinion, which is better in Javascript environment? I used PHP style MVC in one of my projects, but my manager pointed out that my controller is coupled with view.

Comment: In client side js the classic model has more benefits. There are endeavors to also use the classic model server-side via server-push (web sockets, comet) technology. The classic model is better (less coupling, less boilerplate) in general. Model-2 is only a result of request/response web nature constriction.